# Is there any way not to load the Spyder IDE help panel. without having to uncheck in "View->Panes->Help" every time I use it

Tags: ide, spyder

Is there any way not to load the Spyder IDE help panel without having to uncheck in "View->Panes->Help" every time I use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using at least Spyder 5.2.0 you can go to `Tools > Preferences > Plugins` and uncheck `Help`. That will prevent loading the `Help` plugin (will not even be listed in the `View > Panes` menu)

Comment: I'm following these steps, but when I go on the help panel "View->Panes->Help" of spyder IDE and desmarco. If I restart or close Spyder IDE the Help panel loads again. When I do with other panels does not have this behavior. 
spyder                        5.2.0

Comment: That is pending a fix indeed. Here the link to the issue tracking that: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/15331

Comment: I'm going to follow the issue. Thank you very much.